# Moderation of changes to Account record

Tags: lightning, community

**Background**

I would like Partners/Customers to be able to log in their community and update the profile details.

But I would like to be notified of the changes and be able to roll them back / reject them, before the change is permanently applied.

**Question**

How would I moderate changes made to a Account record made via a Partner/Customer community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common workaround is to place all of the changes into some sort of holding spot, and allow whomever is allowed to apply the changes. For example, you could do this in a trigger; check if fields changed, and if they're a partner user, store those changes into a temporary field/object, and revert the changes before saving. Then, approved users can finalize the changes. The other way would be to allow the changes to be saved, but could be undone by a click of a button.

Answer (score 2):

We follow something similar to what sfdcfox has said. Instead we create a customer support case and assign it to an agent. When agent approves and closes the case the data gets populated in the concerned account.